# Fun times with migrating maven projects from netbeans to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netbeans

I have an interesting problem. So, we have a multi-module maven based project, that was originally written on Netbeans. The task is to migrate it to the Eclipse. I imported the project as an existing maven project, which created .project and .classpath files and configured pom's a little.

Now, the entire project looked very ugly - multiple projects all over the place. I found a solution online, to import the project as "Existing Projects into Workspace" and since m2e already created .project/.classpath files, Eclipse recognized it and presented it a nice, top-level view. However, all of the Eclipses functionality is now missing. So, for example, when someone tries to "Open a Declaration" (pressing F3), eclipse spits out this message:

```
Problems opening an editor.

Reason:
[projectname] does not exist
```

Has anyone came across a similar problem or knows where the problem might be?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem. When you import a Maven multi-module project one project will be created for each module (and one for the parent). This is how those multi-module projects are handled in eclipse. So your first approach was the correct one. If there are really plenty of projects you can use working sets to filter out the ones you want to see.

Another way would be to create the eclipse .project files etc by the command line tool by calling `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. Then you can import them as "existing java projects" but you won't get a project containing the parent pom then.

Comment: yeah, seems like it. Netbeans is so much nicer with maven projects though. Total win for Netbeans in this case. Anyway, thanks a bunch for clarifying it :)

Comment: What causes it to show that message when trying to Open a Declaration, though? I've done it before (even in the project I'm currently working on, before it started having this problem).